# How to display some values of javafx combo box before any click on it?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I use a combo that works nice. The only thing i would like to add is to diplay some items(~10) of this box by default at start . I tried to find this property but a hell to find this among all methods.

If somebody knows how to to that

I have the same question for Menubutton

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Do you just want to call `show()` to display the popup?

Comment: show() doesn't work and hang programm. By default combobox menubutton doesn't diplay any items of list until user click on them. My combobox contains about 20items,   I would like to display 10 firsts with a scroll bar (scrollbar is done) but without waiting for the user to click on combobox

Comment: That sounds more like a `ListView` than a `ComboBox`. If `show()` "hangs" your program, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: it s not the program who hangs. just using combobox.show() not allows to select an item anymore because no items displayed with show()

Comment: Again, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just call `show()` on the `ComboBox`. Here is an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboTest  extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) combo.getItems().add("Item "+i);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(combo);
                
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        
        stage.show();
        
        combo.show();

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The same thing works for `MenuButton`.